# Referencing offset cells with INDIRECT() function

Tags: formula, openoffice-calc

Suppose that I have a cell, lets say `Sheet2.A1`, with the value: `Sheet1.A10`. 
It contains the information from where to fetch the data.

Now I would like to fetch this data, which I do with `INDIRECT(Sheet2.A1)`. However, I would further like to extract the data from some cells below in the same column. So suppose I would like to extract data from `Sheet1.A11` and `Sheet1.A12`.

How can I calculate this offset to extract the data?

Is there any extension to the `INDIRECT` function where I can add this offset of one or two columns below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it using `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(Sheet2.A1),1,0)` and `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(Sheet2.A1),2,0)`